# Como quito la comilla "" que vienen por default en StreamWriter de C#

Tags: c#, archivo, filewriter

Los archivos que genero con las librerias stream encierran entre comillas dobles cada linea del archivo genrado, como quito esas comillas. Se supone que NewLine modifica eso, pero no me funciona. Adjunto el siguiente codigo:

```
var NombresTablas = (db.ConfiguracionArchivo.OrderBy(y => y.Id).Select(y => y.NombreTabla).Distinct());
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
{    
    foreach (string NombreTabla in NombresTablas)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        long Id = 0;
        int Secuencia = 0;

        for (int columna = 0; columna < reader.FieldCount; columna++)
        {                   {
            sb.Append(reader.GetValue(columna));
        }

        csvWriter.WriteField(sb);
        csvWriter.NextRecord();
    }
}
writer.NewLine('\n'); writer.Flush();
```

Aplico el newLine para que al guardarse el archivo no se guarde con la comillas dobles. De esta manera:

"BZDET000001112233"

Sino que se guarde de esta otra: BZDET000001112233

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer el valor obtenido mediante `reader.GetValue(columna)` tiene comillas dobles, puedes usar `.Replace("\"", "")` , de esta forma para eliminar las comillas:

```
 sb.Append(reader.GetValue(columna).Replace("\"", ""));
```